# Altering a variable using Functions and Objects

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me what index returns? Im pretty sure it is 0.

```
function jsTest() {

    var index = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    var obj = {};

    obj.index = index;

    var func = function () {
        for (index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            counter += 2;
        }
        obj.index++;    
    };

    obj.func = func;
    this.index++;

    return index;

}
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you run it?

Answer (score 3):

It should be 0. Since the only place that can change local variable `index` is in function `func`, but it doesn't get called. Note that `this.index` is different from local variable `index`. BTW, `this.index++` makes no sense since `this.index` is undefined).

Answer (score 2):

Zero. At least that's what Chrome gave. Also obvious when you see that nothing changes it.

Comment: Well, nothing in the code path that's run changes it, but there's an `index++` in `func`.

Comment: But func is never called

Comment: You're right, but I wouldn't say *nothing* changes it and to an inexperienced JavaScript programmer it may not be so obvious as it is to you.

Comment: Sure. But the point of the original question is.. ?

Comment: i guess i see that it could be changed if func were called. My next question would be how would func be called in this instance?

Comment: I don't know what the point of this question was; it's quite easy to run as you did. However, just saying "oh, it's obvious that it would be zero because nothing changes it!" when there is a change (albeit one in a code path that is not run) I believe is not the best answer you could have given. I think more explanation is due like in Hui Zheng's answer.

Comment: A silly question deserves a silly answer?